# Angular 7 WebSocketSubject. Subscribe path

Tags: angular, websocket, rxjs

I am using WebSocketSubject in Angular7.

```
  this.socket$ = new WebSocketSubject({
    url: 'ws://localhost:8080/bc'
  });
```

Is it possible to subscribe additional path inside this WS? 
e.g. /topic/message

It's like:

```
var socket = new SockJS('/bc');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
stompClient.subscribe('/topic/message'
```

....